# I want to get the ID of the first input with a green color within inputs array and then change the color of that input by its ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get input ID here and use it to change input color to be grey. Then repeat the process for other inputs with green color

```js
var getGreenColor = document.getElementsByClassName("my_inputs")[0].style.color;

if (getGreenColor == "green") {
  console.log("green")
}
else console.log(getGreenColor)
```

```html
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="1" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="2" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="3" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="4" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is exactly, but instead of `.color`, the property you want is `.style.color`; maybe that's what you are after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand, you want to change all inputs with green color text to grey. If that were the case, you would want to get the elements in question by doing the following:

```
var greenInputsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("my_inputs");
```

And then you could loop through the array and if the color is green, you can change the color to grey as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < greenInputsArray.length; i++) {
    if(greenInputsArray[i].style.color == "green") {
       greenInputsArray[i].style.color = "grey";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you're not going to be using inline styling, you should try @mplungjan answer, or you could just use jQuery which would make that process much simpler.

Comment: Yeah I'm using jQuery. @mplungjan answer is great too. I wish I could accept both answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the style.color or getComputedStyle

The style.color is undefined if not inline

```js
const getColor = ele => ele.style.color || window.getComputedStyle(ele).color;

document.querySelectorAll(".my_inputs").forEach((ele,i) => {
  const color = getColor(ele);
  console.log(i,color)
  if (color === "green" || color === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
    ele.style.color = "grey"
  }
})
```

```css
#id1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="id2" class="my_inputs" value="stuff" />
<input type="text" id="id1" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="id3" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: red;" id="id4" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="id5" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('my_inputs');
for (let a=0; a < elements.length; a++) {
    if (elements[a].style.color == 'green') {
        elements[a].style.color = 'grey';
    }
}
```

This will loop through the elements and if it is green, turn it to grey.

Comment: No it won't. Try it

Answer (score 0):

You could also you css attribute selector if your color is always set inline:

```css
input[style="color: green;"]:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="1" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="2" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="3" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
<input type="text" style="color: green;" id="4" class="my_inputs" value="stuff">
```